# eclipse several ant build file

Tags: eclipse, file, ant, build

currently I'm developing in eclipse 3.5 in different project web applications for tomcat 6.0.24.

For each of this project I have written a ant build file to generate the war file to deploy the project to the tomcat container.

So I have to run for each project the ant build file (a lot of clicks, and a waste of time).

Question: Is there a possibility to run all needed ant build files with a single click, from a single project or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. E.g., you could create a master build file and use the `Exec` task.

Answer (score 3):

@thelost

thank you very much for your hint, you brought me on the right way,
I solved the problem:

```
<target name="build">
    <ant antfile="jar-build.xml" target="GEN-JAR_FILES" />
    <ant antfile="war-service01.xml" target="SVC01-WAR"/>
    <ant antfile="war-service02.xml" target="SVC02-WAR"/>
</target>
```

best regards, Alex